# Pre-render multiple pages from single HTML page using Nuxt.js

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js, static-site

I have a supplied HTML file with content in separate `<section>` tags.

I need to pre-render these sections into individual static pages during build time using Nuxt (preferably) or other generator.

Supplied HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>...</header>
    <section id="home">...</section>
    <section id="features">...</section>
    <section id="about">...</section>
    <section id="contact">...</section>
    <footer>...</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Static pages to generate during build:

`index.html`, `features.html`, `about.html` and `contact.html`

with each page containing the common `<head>`, `<header>` and `<footer>` content.

How do I do this?

For context: The supplied HTML is coming from a site builder so I have no control over the output. I need to generate individual static pages because the final site will be hosted on static hosting like S3.

Comment: Have you already the documentation for generating based on static hosting? https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands/ - Looks like you are looking for `npm run generate`

Comment: Well, you need to write your own parser for that html

Comment: @MikeDiglio yes, I read those docs, thanks, but I'm new to Nuxt and this is something of an edge case so I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: @Aldarund Cool, thanks. Sounds like something I can't handle myself so I'll post it on a job board.